# cant connect to local mysql server through socket when trying to connect to VM from host

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I'm working on cloud computing. My network setting for VM is .. Adapter 1:host only adapter Adapter 2: NAT.im trying to connect from host to MySQL server that is in my virtual machine.i had to change the bind address in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to IP of host .now I'm not able to connect to MySQL

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

throws error

```
   "cant connect to local MySQL server through socket"
```

the error.log tells that TCP/IP issue. what should i do?

Comment: I think you didn't started your database server.

Comment: Try this command : #services mysql start or #/etc/init.d/mysql start

Comment: What do you mean by, "the error.log tells that TCP/IP issue."?

Comment: thanku :) i solved the issue myself.here is my solution.

Comment: thanku :) i solved the issue myself.here is my solution. 
In vm select Settings->Network->Adapter1 set as Host Only Adapter.Settings->Network->Adapter2 set as NAT.Disable Firewall in Host and VM.Update and upgrade VM using linux commands.  Install Mysql using “sudo apt-get install mysql-server” .Navigate to config file and change bind address to 0.0.0.0.Restart mysql service. Navigate to mysql.grant all on *.* to ‘root’@’%’ identified by  ‘grant password’.run the java code from host machine using IDE.Give the database connectivity DB_URL as "jdbc:mysql://hostonly adap ip dbname”